# Functions for which the Jacobian has orthogonal columns or rows

Tags: matrices, special-functions, orthogonality, mobius-transformation, jacobian

What can be said about a function $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for which all singular values of the Jacobian matrix, $\mathbf{J}$, are all 1?

I have found [this similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228964/functions-with-orthogonal-jacobian) which covers the case for functions $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, but [conformal mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Higher-dimensional_Euclidean_space) and, more specifically [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Higher_dimensions), do not seem to apply to the more general case where $m \neq n$.

One possible way of generalising the results anyway, would be to extend the domain or image of $f$ to get a function $f' : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k$ with $k = \max(m, n)$ where vectors from the domain or image of $f$ are filled up with zeros (or in some other way) in the additional dimensions. I have no idea, however, in how far this makes sense or is a valid thing to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.